# How to click a button that is located in other class than method

Tags: java, javafx

I have an issue with firing a button that is located in another class.

I've tried passing button in parameter, but I'm getting null exception error same goes for getter that I've created.

```
public class ButtonHolder{
    @FXML
    RadioButton radioButton;

    public void radioButtonOnClick(){
        //does something
    }
    public RadioButton getRadioButton(){
        return this.radioButton;
    }
}


public class Example{
    public void fireButton(){
        ButtonHolder buttonHolder = new ButtonHolder();
        buttonHolder.getRadioButton.fire();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add to this question the minimum amount of code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: here you go that's fast example what i'm trying to do

Comment: `radioButton` is not initialized after creating an instance of `ButtonHolder` resulting in the NPE. There simply is no button to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem**

XML (I assume you have XML layout) not connected to your code.

**Solution**

A better approach in terms of architecture would be to separate"business" logic from UI logic. Let's say you have some code inside `radioButtonOnClick`.

- Move the code to a new class to its own merhod
- Add said class as a dependency to both of your classes;
- Run new method from both of your classes.

**What if I need to use button**

You can create it:

```
//A button with an empty text caption.
Button button1 = new Button();
```

And then call `fire ()`.

**What if control element doesn't have `fire` method**

here's example for `RadioMenuItem` with `EventHandler`:

```
MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();

Menu menu = new Menu("Menu 1");

RadioMenuItem choice1Item = new RadioMenuItem("Choice 1");
choice1Item.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("radio toggled");
    }
});
RadioMenuItem choice2Item = new RadioMenuItem("Choice 2");
RadioMenuItem choice3Item = new RadioMenuItem("Choice 3");

ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();
toggleGroup.getToggles().add(choice1Item);
toggleGroup.getToggles().add(choice2Item);
toggleGroup.getToggles().add(choice3Item);

menu.getItems().add(choice1Item);
menu.getItems().add(choice2Item);
menu.getItems().add(choice3Item);

menuBar.getMenus().add(menu);

VBox vBox = new VBox(menuBar);

Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 300, 275);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

**What if I want to use button from XML**

Take a look at the FXML tutorial:
https://riptutorial.com/javafx/example/5125/example-fxml

Comment: Thank you for feedback, what should i do for RadioMenuItem because it just don't have method called fire

Comment: @Wikimmax Please, take a look at `RadioMenuItem` example.